# scraping data table from clinicaltrials.gov with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to scrape this data table when I put in search terms on [clinicaltrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/). Specifically, I'd like to scrape the table you see on this page: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=nivolumab+AND+Overall+Survival. See below for screenshot:

[image]

I've tried this code, but I don't think I got the right css selector:

```
# create custom url
ctgov_url <- "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=nivolumab+AND+Overall+Survival"
# read HTML page
ct_page <- rvest::read_html(ctgov_url)

# extract related terms
ct_page %>%
  # find elements that match a css selector
  rvest::html_element("t") %>%
  # retrieve text from element (html_text() is much faster than html_text2())
  rvest::html_table()
```

Comment: You can't use rvest for that page. The data you are looking for is not in the page source code. The data is loaded later via javascript. Rvest cannot run javascript code for you. You can either reverse engineer the site to try to see where it's pulling the data from and recrate such calls, or use something like Rselenium which can run javascript for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `rvest` here at all. The page provides a download button to get a csv of the search items. This has a basic url-encoded GET syntax which allows you to create a simple little API:

```r
get_clin_trials_data <- function(terms, n = 1000) {
  
  terms<- URLencode(paste(terms, collapse = " AND "))

  df <- read.csv(paste0(
    "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/download_fields",
    "?down_count=", n, "&down_flds=shown&down_fmt=csv",
    "&term=", terms, "&flds=a&flds=b&flds=y"))

  dplyr::as_tibble(df)
}
```

This allows you to pass in a vector of search terms and a maximum number of results to return. No need for complex parsing as would be required with web scraping.

```r
get_clin_trials_data(c("nivolumab", "Overall Survival"), n = 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 8
#>     Rank Title     Status Study.Results Conditions Interventions Locations URL  
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>         <chr>      <chr>         <chr>     <chr>
#>  1     1 A Study ~ Compl~ No Results A~ Hepatocel~ ""            "Bristol~ http~
#>  2     2 Nivoluma~ Activ~ No Results A~ Glioblast~ "Drug: Nivol~ "Duke Un~ http~
#>  3     3 Nivoluma~ Unkno~ No Results A~ Melanoma   "Biological:~ "CHU d'A~ http~
#>  4     4 Study of~ Compl~ Has Results   Advanced ~ "Biological:~ "Highlan~ http~
#>  5     5 A Study ~ Unkno~ No Results A~ Brain Met~ "Drug: Fotem~ "Medical~ http~
#>  6     6 Trial of~ Compl~ Has Results   Squamous ~ "Drug: Nivol~ "Stanfor~ http~
#>  7     7 Nivoluma~ Compl~ No Results A~ MGMT-unme~ "Drug: Nivol~ "New Yor~ http~
#>  8     8 Study of~ Compl~ Has Results   Squamous ~ "Biological:~ "Mayo Cl~ http~
#>  9     9 Study of~ Compl~ Has Results   Non-Squam~ "Biological:~ "Mayo Cl~ http~
#> 10    10 An Open-~ Unkno~ No Results A~ Squamous-~ "Drug: Nivol~ "IRCCS -~ http~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, is there a way to include NCT Number column in the result? On the website, you can show  NCT Number column in the result table by clicking "Show/Hide Columns", but I'm not sure how you would do this in your function.

Comment: @HowardBaek sure, I think you would change `"&flds=a&flds=b&flds=y"` to `"&flds=a&flds=b&flds=k&flds=y"`